# Is it possible to decorate the descriptive title text of a theorem by enclosing it within a TikZ node?

Tags: theorems

Using `\newtcbtheorem (tcolorbox)`, is it possible to decorate the descriptive title text of a theorem by enclosing it within a tikz node such as starburst or cloud? Sorry, there is no MWE as I could not figure out the necessary syntax at all.

Comment: At least you should provide the community with an idea of what you mean by "starburst" or "cloud": search on the Internet, find some pictures and post them here, highlighting what you're after.

Comment: Some people take exception to questions of the form "Please do this for me". You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). You have said that a MWE is not possible but couldn't you give us the code for setting up a tcolorbox theorem environment and then say more clearly how you would like to modify its output?